# Put quotes around every word in a line

Tags: bash

Not sure if this is possible, but I have a list of values like this:

```
#value,
#value2,
#value-3
```

Some have dashes in them, and the last line doesn't have a comma. I need to put single quotes around every word, like this:

```
#'value',
#'value2',
#'value3'
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sed`.

Suppose your list is in `list.txt`

```
sed "s/^#\([^,]*\)\(,\?\)$/#\'\1\'\2/" < list.txt
```

will work as follows.

It will replace every line that

1. starts with `#`. In sed this is written as `^#`
2. has a sequence of characters that does not contain a comma - `\([^,]*\)`
3. and optionally a comma - `\(,\?\)`
4. and nothing else - `$`

with a line that
has `#`, an apostrophe `` \` ``, first sequence `\1`, another apostrophe and the second sequence `\2`.

Here we go

```
sed "s/^#\([^,]*\)\(,\?\)$/#\'\1\'\2/" <<END
> #value,
> #value2,
> #value-3
> .
> END
#'value',
#'value2',
#'value-3'
.
```

Comment: @Pete here is an example, sort of.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
sed "s/^#\([^,]*\)\(.*\)/#'\1'\2/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$1 = "#\047" substr($1, 2) "\047"} 1' file

#'value',
#'value2',
#'value-3'
```